# json data in table for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4

I am unable to display json data obtained through asynchronous `HttpRequest` in my table. 
I do not have an `IBOutlet` for tableView was I make that table in my code by implementing delegate methods of `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: I tried to print the number of rows in console but the code fails to go at that point...

Comment: sorry I am trying but I am new and don't know formatting

Comment: Please _edit_ your question to provide more information. The editor help is easily found when editing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delare `yourTable` in .h file also make IBOutlet for this and make proper connection.

.h file

```
IBOutlet UITableView *yourTable;
```

also make connection for the delegate and datasource for tableView with file's owner.

Then reload your table in `connectiDidFinishLoading`

```
[yourTable reloadData];
```

Comment: but then how do I link yourTable with tableView?

Comment: yourTable is the name for table you can give whatevre you want then use that iVar name for access the table. means don't need to write tableView.

Comment: Also for making connection open xib select file's owner then you will see you iboutlets in connetion inspector. then make connection with table the select table in xib the connect datasource and delegate with file's owner.

Comment: if I change tableView to yourTable I get a compiler warning that the local declaration of yourTable hides instance variable in cellFOrRowAtIndexpath method

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath, no need to redeclare the yourTable use tableView(it is an argument for the method). and [yourTable reloadData] line is for connectionDidFinishLoad

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the tableView and you are in the tableViewController, you can use:

```
self.tableView
```

If you are not in the controller, keep a pointer to this controller or to the tableView directly.
Declare it in the .h and link it in the IB file.

Then call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: since I make tableView in tableview delegate method, I don't have access to it in connectionDidFinishLoading method